# node js grpc server forceShutdown doesn't shut down properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, grpc

I'm trying to restart a grpc node js server after shutting it down

The first time the grpc server starts it is ok, but trying to start after forceShutdown gives the error:

```
Error: Server is already running
```

This is the code:

```
server.start(); // runs ok 
server.forceShutdown();
server.start(); // gives error
```

How to shut down grpc server properly so that it can be restarted like above?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a bug on gRPC's part. According to their docs:

> When it returns, the server has shut down.

Meaning that when the function call returns, the server *should* be shut down, but it doesn't seem like that's the case as illustrated by your issue. You could try calling for a graceful shutdown and passing a callback that should be executed when the server has been shut down, and then immediately afterwards call for a forceful shutdown:

```
server.start();
server.tryShutdown(function () {
  server.start();
});
server.forceShutdown();
```

Comment: I actually found the answer here, so it's only possible to start a server if you instantiate another server (https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/7031)